# Proof involving the Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

Hi all I have this question from a lecture that I had earlier, the lecturer left the proof as an excercise. I asked him later in the week after a couple attempts and he said I should use proof by induction on n. I had another few cracks at it but I still haven't got anywhere with it. Any help would be very much appreciated. The question is:

"Let $f : R → R$ be a polynomial function of degree $n$ and let $a ∈ R$. Show that
the $nth$ Taylor polynomial $P_{f,a,n}$ of $f$ at $a$ is equal to $f$, i.e. that $P_{f,a,n}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x ∈ R.$"

Comment: Show what you tried to do and we will be able to help you.

Comment: You are trying to prove that the Taylor polynomial of a polynomial is that polynomial basically?

Comment: I think so and I'm sorry I threw my workings away cause it didn't get me anywhere. I can try to replicate it if you really want but its basically useless.

Comment: Abstractly, when $g$ is a sufficiently often differentiable function, what do you know about $$g(x) - P_{g,a,n}(x)\,?$$

Comment: Would it go to 0?

Comment: As $x$ approaches what? And how fast?

Comment: It would be for any value of x and the speed would depend on the number of terms in the Taylor series surely?

Comment: I mean for a fixed $n$ (and $a$), only $x$ varies.

Comment: I'm not sure then in that case.